# Silverstripe Fluent locale selection based on domain name

Tags: silverstripe, fluent, silverstripe-4

Am I correct in assuming that Silverstripe Fluent is supposed to switch the site locale based on the domain name used to access the site?

I have set-up a fluent site with english, french and german locales and assigned a domain name to each locale (site.mysite.com, desite.mysite.com and frsite.mysite.com) and also set the locale of each site to the en_GB, de_DE and fr_FR respectively.

It was my understanding that if I visit frsite.mysite.com then I should be presented with the French version of the site, desite.mysite.com with the German version of the site and site.mysite.com with the English version of the site, however, all three URL's present the English version of the site.

If I visit site.mysite.com/fr or frsite.mysite.com/fr or desite.mysite.com/fr I get the french version.

I am using Silverstripe V4.02 and Fluent V3.3 (I think!)

I have set SS_FLUENT_FORCE_DOMAIN="true" in my .env file and running in live mode.

Am I doing something wrong or does it not have this functionality?

Comment: Good question! What you've described sounds like it should be working. Have you set "global default" to true for the main locale on each domain?

Comment: Yes, I have the following:
Domains:

Domain                    Default    Locales
site.mysite.com English en_GB
desite.mysite.com German de_DE
frsite.mysite.com French fr_FR

Locales:

TITLE  LOCALE    URL  GLOBAL    DOMAIN  
German de_DE   de         0           desite.mysite.com 
English en_GB   en         1                site.mysite.com 
French fr_FR   fr         0           frsite.mysite.com

Comment: You can be sure about the versions that you are using of fluent by viewing the composer.lock for or running  composer show -i package/name so you can be sure whats installed. v3.3 won't work on ss4

Comment: I was going by the latest version in the changelog! Checking the composer.lock file it would appear that I am using 4.0.0

Comment: if you have flushed all the caches and double checked that everything matches then there is a possibility, a low one, that the PHP wont get the right domain name in its  $_SERVER variable

Comment: Which server variable does Fluent use?

Comment: @PhillBex what it uses you can check through the extensions codes. But as a quick check just var_dump or phpinfo() and view does that contain somewhere the wrong domain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed by removing `SS_BASE_URL` from .env.